# C# 4.0 Task Library deadlock

Tags: c#, .net, sql

I am experimenting with this code:

```
        foreach (var r in _vm.Rules.Take(20)) {
            Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
                new SQLRuleSerializer().SaveRule(_vm.SelectedKey, r);
            });             
        }
```

Error:

> Transaction (Process ID 600) was deadlocked on lock resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction.

I am not sure exactly how this is deadlocking considering i do not have any explicit locks.. i guess the problems is that serializer is a proxy and cannot be called in parallel even via separate instances?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Transaction (Process ID 600) was deadlocked on lock resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction.

The deadlock is coming from the SQL Server, not the C# code.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to save 20 different rules in parallel, but it seems each save requires some locks on the SQL server. This means that there's most likely no gain in parallelizing, so you should use normal loop without using TPL.